# Spikes in raw acceleration data from AC motor

Tags: microcontroller, motor, signal-processing, isolation, accelerometer

I have an MCU with an accelerometer, tightly mounted onto an AC motor inside a production hall.

Once an hour, it collects 1 sec. (Sample rate is 5000) of acceleration data for the motor and saves it.

When I try to display this data, I get these weird spikes:

[image: Raw data from Accelerometer]

**Can somebody tell me, what these spikes/artifacts could be?**

I'm sure my import/chart setup is correct, so I'm pretty sure it's an issue with my components.

**Extra info:**
The components are located inside a plastic box that's mounted with a metal backplate. Everything should be electrically isolated from the AC motor.
When testing in office environment (On a test motor), these spikes did not occur.

- Accelerometer: [ADXL357](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adxl357.html#product-overview)
- MCU: [FRDM-K64F](https://www.nxp.com/design/development-boards/freedom-development-boards/mcu-boards/freedom-development-platform-for-kinetis-k64-k63-and-k24-mcus:FRDM-K64F)

EDIT:
I come from software - I'm pretty new to hardware and electronics, so bear with me, thanks! :-)

Comment: My guess is induced noise. Do you get those spikes if it is in almost the same location but not mounted to detect vibration?

Comment: @DKNguyen I have not tested that yet (I only have access to the production hall every now and then). But these spikes was first introduced in my results after I took the components in to the production. When I was sitting at my desk, I didn't have any issues. I also had an AC motor at my desk to test with, and this didn't produce the issue either.

Comment: I don't know what your production hall looks like, but in my mind production halls are very different from office desks, even with a single AC motor. Maybe it or something it is mounted to is just getting banged every now and  then from outside. Need more info.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think you might be right about it being induced noise. Asking as an electronics newbie, do you think the induced noise comes from the components them selves, or from external sources? Because you're right, there are a lot of different machines running near it.

Comment: It's both but huge spikes like that tend to come from without rather than within. Noise from within components tends to be constant low levels similar to static.

Answer (score 8):

The spikes seem to have a few common heights that are roughly related by factors of 2, which strongly suggests that they are noise-induced single-bit errors in the binary data.

One good way to address this is to take the standard deviation of all the data, and then simply throw away any samples that are more than, say, 2σ from the mean.

Another technique is to use a median-value filter, which looks at a sliding window of, say, 3 or 5 samples, and replaces the middle sample with the median value of the samples in the window. I've used this technique to remove "salt and pepper noise" (same problem) in video data.

---

Simply post-processing the data as described above might be adequate for your purposes of monitoring equipment health, etc. But if you want to find and fix the root cause of the bit errors, you'll need to focus on the digital communications paths in the system:

- between the accelerometer and the MCU
- between the MCU and the system where you're analyzing the data

Switching the plastic box to a metal one might be a good first step, especially for the upper bullet item. Shielded cable (if you're not already using it) would help with the second item.

Comment: Yes, data errors would be my suspect as well - but I'd consider *design faults* as well as induced error.  One test worth doing is figuring out a way to mount a sensor in a similar environment but decoupled from the machinery and see if it still exhibits such spikes.  Also worth checking bus timings (at least if SPI is used), and even looking for buffering faults in the software.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Yes, finding and fixing the root cause might be useful in some situations, but for the purposes of monitoring equipment health and if the errors remain rare enough, it's more effective to simply post-process the data you have.

Comment: This can be a system issue, often sampling interfaces have caveats you may be unaware of, I had to track down a bit flip error like this in ADC sampling, the root cause was issuing asynchronous commands to the adc while the device was updating its itself, causing mixed data  exactly exxagerated at word boundary  overflows . In that case root cause was firmware timing hiccups as the issue was intrinsic behavior of ADC.  But it is not clear to me if this is a single buffered set from the accelerometer or what are the details of the sample collection.

Comment: @crasic: In this case, the ADCs are part of the accelerometer itself, so we can assume that their operation has been debugged by Analog Devices. I have a lot of experience with various ADI accelerometer chips, and they're generally quite good.

Comment: Not necessarily, there is i2c interface that is connected to internal registers, there are timing caveats with i2c and spi  sensors like this abound, detailed in the datasheet, just a suggestion to check that as well.

Comment: Here is an example, your sample  is near a byte boundary, `0x00ff` and `0x0100` , the internal of the device might use a simple shift register for i2c interface.    If this is not accounted for by the device designer , you can get a mixed sample on the bus 0x01ff . This is a somewhat annoying higher order issue with polling simple  serial sampling devices in general.  If one doesn't use i2c/spi or always uses the right devices and proper implementation perhaps they may never encounter it but I always try to sniff the bus and verify the system before committing  to an electrical investigation.

Comment: It's also possible to make sign extension errors when reassembling multibyte values in software which interprets them, and in quiet or unluckily biased settings to not see the issue until the low byte excursion reaches a value misinterpreted as "negative"

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions! I'll definitely look into these! My setup design is far from perfect, so there is a good chance some of your suggestions might do the trick. I've too thought about just removing the spikes in post processing, and that might be my last resort.

Comment: Post processing works to an extent, and if it can be proven as electrical noise it is likely long term reliable if it is predictable, but timing issues I wouldn't leave as they are often inherently unpredictable,  they fester and will pop up unexpectedly when you try to change the system or add features.

Comment: @ClaesZacho - As an example of the problem described by *Chris Stratton* above when reassembling (in this case) 16-bit data values, see this question: "[MPU6050 accel/gyro noise that behaves strangely - what might be doing this?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/333174)". The OP was reporting similar unexpected spikes, with a few common heights (values), in their accelerometer's I2C data. The cause was found to be in their code, as explained in the answers there.